# How to integrate GraphQL query in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, graphql

I am struggling in understanding the way to make a POST API call to a GraphQL server through my kotlin application.

I have taken a look at various guides, like these ones: https://graphql.org/code/#java-kotlin and https://opensource.expediagroup.com/graphql-kotlin/docs/client/client-overview/ but I was not able to understand how to implement them.

First of all the initial Build Configuration is not clear to me, since every guide talks about a build.gradle.kts file that I do not have. My gradel is just "build.gradle" and I don't know the way to turn it into "build.gradle.kts". Simply adding this code:

```
import com.expediagroup.graphql.plugin.gradle.graphql

plugins {
    id("com.expediagroup.graphql") version $latestGraphQLKotlinVersion
}

dependencies {
  implementation("com.expediagroup:graphql-kotlin-spring-client:$latestGraphQLKotlinVersion")
}

graphql {
    client {
        endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/graphql"
        packageName = "com.example.generated"
    }
}
```

returns me the error:
build file 'C:\Users\claud\AndroidStudioProjects\ShareValley\app\build.gradle': 1: unable to resolve class com.expediagroup.graphql.plugin.gradle.graphql
@ line 1, column 1.
import com.expediagroup.graphql.plugin.gradle.graphql

In addition, I am used to call APIs through the volley package in kotlin. Is there a way to call a GraphQL API using it?

Is there anyone able to provide me a working example or at least explain to me how this build.gradle.kts works?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a few issues going on here.

1. can't build project:
   It doesn't matter that you don't have the `build.gradle.kts` file. You can use your `build.gradle` file. That just means you are using a different language to write your gradle scripts (probably Groovy). In that case, you should be using the following syntax inside your dependencies block. Notice the single quote and no parentheses.

```
implementation 'group:package:version'
```

1. Making the actual GraphQL call: GraphQL is a protocol, so this client here is not necessary if your goal is to simply make an API call to a GraphQL server. You can write a plain old Http request. For graphQL, you should construct an `application/json` request body with the following structure. more info https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/

```
{
 "query" : "graphql query (look up syntax)",
 "variables" : { "some var" : "some value", ... },
 "operationName": "some name"
}
```

**EDIT**
P.S. You should use a client, though, if you want to use GraphQL throughout your Kotlin app. Clients help reduce GraphQL config boilerplate code and, more importantly, handle cacheing for you. Well, a good one should.